# ASP.Net how can I display information related to dropdown list value into a textbox from database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database, oracle

table 1: Applications

table 2: Items related to Application

ok so i have a form with a dropdown list displaying the Applications and i want every time i change the value of the selected application name to display all items under that application from the database.

so far i have a connection to my database and everything i just cant figure out how to display the information that show up in a textbox or label or even better the checkbox list i have.

my UI: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDajt.png)

```
  using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace task1
{
    public partial class application_info_form : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OracleConnection objConn;
        OracleCommand objCmd;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                   Fill_Apps();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.PopulateCheckList();
            }


        

        }

        private void PopulateCheckList()
        {
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["apps_connectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select search_item_id , search_item_name from search_item_table ORDER BY search_item_name";
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.Text = sdr["search_item_name"].ToString();
                            item.Value = sdr["search_item_id"].ToString();

                            chkList_Search_Item.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void App_DDL()
        {
            string DDL_Val = "";
            DDL_Val = ddl_appName.SelectedValue;

            String strSQL;
            strSQL = "select * from search_item_table_app where application_id = '" + DDL_Val + "'";



        }
     
        private void Fill_Apps()
        {
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["apps_connectionString"].ConnectionString;
            objConn = new OracleConnection(strConnString);
            objConn.Open();

            String strSQL = "select application_id , application_name from PORTAL.ua_application where status = 'Y' order by application_name";

            OracleDataReader dtReader;
            objCmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, objConn);
            dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);
           

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset  



            //*** BindData to GridView ***//
            ddl_appName.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["application_name"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown       
            ddl_appName.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["application_id"].ToString();


            ddl_appName.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist  
            ddl_appName.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist  
            //ddl_appName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- select --"));


            dtReader.Close();
            dtReader.Dispose();
            dtReader = null;
            objConn.Close();
            objConn.Dispose();

        }

       

        protected void ddl_appName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
                String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["apps_connectionString"].ConnectionString;
                objConn = new OracleConnection(strConnString);
                objConn.Open();

                string id = ddl_appName.SelectedValue;
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from search_item_table_app where application_id ='" + id +"'", objConn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
           
                txtbdescription.Text = dt.ToString();
            txtbdescription.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            objConn.Close();
            
            







        }

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things:

a drop down list can consume or be "feed" a whole table.

but, if you feed the ddl a whole table, then which columns is the ddl to use?

That is what the test two settings are:

```
ddl_appName.DataTextField = "application_name";
ddl_appName.DataValueField = "application_id";
```

NOTE close in above: The TextField and Value field settings in above are ONLY the name of the columns to use - NOT THAT you try to put into that setting the actual column value - it TELLS the ddl what columns to use.

So, your code could and should look like this to load the combo box:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // we only need to load one time - !IsPostBack
            LoadCombo();
        }
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        ddl_appName.DataValueField = "application_id";
        ddl_appName.DataTextField = "application_name";

        String strSQL 
            = "select application_id , application_name from PORTAL.ua_application " +
              "where status = 'Y' order by application_name";
        
        ddl_appName.DataSource = MyRst(new OracleCommand(strSQL));
        ddl_appName.DataBind();
        // optional blank - no choice for ddl
        ddl_appName.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select app","0")));

    }

    DataTable MyRst(OracleCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["apps_connectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                objConn.Open();
                cmdSQL.Connection = objConn;
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

Ok, so above takes care of loading the ddl.

We assume that you have some ddl, and autopostback = true.

Say like this:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_appName" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_appName_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

So, when user select a ddl, then our code runs and we get the data.

```
    protected void ddl_appName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string strSQL
            = "select * from search_item_table_app " +
              "where application_id = @AppID";
        OracleCommand cmdSQL = new OracleCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@AppID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = ddl_appName.SelectedValue;

        DataTable dt = MyRst(cmdSQL);
        DataRow MyRow = dt.Rows[0];

        txtbdescription.Text = MyRow["Descripton"].ToString();
        txtAppName.Text = MyRow["ApplicaitonName"];
        // etc. etc. etc.
    }
```

So a few things:

While for 30 years, since the dawn of computers? We as a general rule don't want to re-open the connection over and over. However, asp.net - and .net in general is a EXCEPTION to this long time rule. In other words, .net will maintain behind the scenes a connection pool for you. It is automatic,  and automatic re-used. As a result, we can freely dispose and close out the connection, but behind the scenes the .net management system with millions of dollars of R&D will re-use and re-cycle the connection for you. So do NOT try to maintain this on your own.

There are some cases in which of course you might create a connection object, re-use it a few times, but for the most part are you 100% free to simple "dispose" of the connection object. And you REALLY do want to ensure that .net does this disposing for you correctly, and use the using block of code - always!!! (if  you try and maintain that connection object, then you mess up the connection pool that doing that job for you!!!).

Strong suggest you adopt the using block, since it will THEN manage the connection pooling behind the scenes for you, and you NOT chew up the connection pool. As noted, it seems and sounds great to try and persist you OWN connection object (as you did at the page class level scope), but don't!!! - the system manages this for you, but ONLY if you consistent adopt "using" blocks, and let .net dispose of the connection object. As I stated, behind the scenes there is a HUGE boatload of .net code that will automatic re-cycle and re-using the connection automatic over and over - so don't try to maintain or manage or keep in memory your OWN connection object - it is 100% automatic managed for you - and that includes speed - once one open connection has occurred, then .net behind the scenes will hold, re-use, and re-cycle that connection for you. Hence, DO FEEL free in code to create the connection object on demand - it not a problem, and it will not be slow. This whole approach ONLY breaks down if you attempt to cache or persist you OWN connection object - DON'T!!! This is counter intuitive to everyone and everything we been taught and used with computers. But do let .net manage this for you. Fighting this will often cause the connection pool to get overloaded. So, create the connection object on demand - the system behind will actually keep a copy active and re-use it for YOUR new connection object!!!

So, the above is a basic break-down. You messed up with some addtonal grid view code - and it not clear how that fits into above.

But, MOST imporant?
It was use of the !IsPostBack test. We ONLY load that ddl one time on load. After that, we don't re-load due to the !IsPostback.

And the same would apply to the GV - it not clear however how that code fits into this question.

Also, we did risk some sql injection here, and we do grab/get the value of the ddl and shoved it into the sql string - we in th

Comment: thank you so much for the answer though it seems like it cut by the end. i will do all the suggested fixes and see how it goes. though idk what is the right way to use the oracle connection. the GV and Label were made so i can populate the corresponding info from my DB that connects application table with item search but i still dk how i can do that. NOTE: im new to learning all of this!

Comment: All good. You can fill the GV with the MyRst() routine also - it kind of handy and saves a lot of typing of connection and data reader over and over.  so, your connection code was fine - and the posted sample MyRst() also is fine. So, after you say select the ddl, you can now fill out a few text boxes on the page as my sample code, or even send a query based on that ddl to the grid view. The code to fill gv is 100% the same as above in how we filled the ddl. (set datasource, and then do a databind). Sorry for the really long notes about the connection. (but using block and you fine).

Comment: if you can link me to learning material to how to use using block ?

Comment: off the top of my head, I don't have a link, but the MyRstP() routine in above has a great example of how to do this. The "using" block of code of course closes the connection object , and does a "dispose" for you automatic. So there is not really much more to this concept. If you don't have "using" block, then in code do a conn.Close(), and probably a conn.Dispose(). So "using" does all that for you. And thus you assume in code that the connection was always closed after u done.  And say sql errors out? Once again, then did your code leave a stray connection open? With using that don't occur